# What is the name/type of this shutter hinge?

Tags: hinges, shutters

I am trying to locate a hinge for plantation shutters and my googling has not turned up much.  I think I am not using the right vocabulary--does this type of hinge have a more specific name?

[image: Non-descript shutter hinge]

Answer (score 1):

I found something and they are called "Swing Clear Hinge"

[swing](https://www.hardwaresource.com/economical-swing-clear-hinge.html?variant_id=56138)

You best choice is to search "swing free hinges"

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this could be called a non-mortise wrap hinge.

It could probably be called other things as well, but that's the closest equivalent I've found in a quick search.